# how to set open office as my default program

Tags: openoffice.org

I installed open office 3.4 in my system Ubuntu 12.04 by following steps

1. download Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_3.4.0_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US tar file
2. and extract the file manually and `cd en-US`
3. `cd DEBS`
4. `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` & `cd desktop-integration` again use same command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Here how can I set openoffice as my default program

Answer (score 0):

You can set as default from right click on document-->properties tab-->open with OpenOffice-->set as default

Answer (score 0):

When right clicking on a document you want to open by default with Open Office, you can open properties and there is a menu saying `open with`. There you should be able to select Open Office and set it as the default app for that operation.

Comment: i want to set open office as default program for os level not for a single document

Comment: This adds OpenOffice as default program for this type of document you were execution this action at.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter This command in terminal

   sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list

Search for your office:

```
find /usr/share/applications/ -name *office*
```

Then change `libreoffice-writer.desktop` to your search result.

Add these line if they don't exist

```
application/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/msexcel=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/msword=libreoffice-writer.desktop
text/rtf=libreoffice-writer.desktop
text/spreadsheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop
text/tab-separated-values=libreoffice-calc.desktop
text/x-comma-separated-values=libreoffice-calc.desktop
```

You can set any application as default.

Comment: These lines are pointing libre office but i neeed open office as a by default program

Comment: Update my answer .

Comment: i installed open office and i can see it by typing following command i.e ./soffice.binbut i cant find it on my system

Comment: i installed open office and i can see it by typing following command i.e /opt/openoffice.org3/program$./soffice.bin but                   i cant find it on my system search and also other programs list

Comment: Do you install office in /opt

Comment: Yes, openoffice is installed in /opt/openoffice.org3.